# How to set up grunt task for Jest?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, gruntjs, jestjs

I need to run my jest command for unit testing react application using grunt. Is there any way I can set up a grunt task for the same and configure it to execute the jest command? Currently I am using `npm run test` to execute jest. For the same I have configured my `package.json` with a test script that executes jest.

```
"test": "jest"
```

How can I achieve the same using Grunt task?

Comment: See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057651/2079735

Comment: let me give that a  shot. looks helpful!

Comment: Check this answer, worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304117/5346095